# Get node value if attribute doesn't exist

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file who contains multiple elements with same name but differents attributes.

```
<ns3:ExportMedicines>
  <ns3:Jkm code="35897">
    <ns3:Data from="2016-10-01" to="2020-07-21">
      <ns2:Name>
        <Fr>estradiol 1 mg comp + estradiol 1 mg + dydrogestérone 10 mg comp</Fr> 
      </ns2:Name>
    </ns3:Data>
    <ns3:Data from="2020-07-22">
      <ns2:Name>
        <Fr>estradiol 1 mg comp+ estradiol 1 mg + dydrogestérone 10 mg comp</Fr>
      </ns2:Name>
    </ns3:Data>
  </ns3:Jkm>
</ns3:ExportMedicines>
```

I would like to get the more recent `<ns3:data>` element.
I'm using xsl 1.0 so as i already read i can't test date attributes.
So i think one way to do is to test if the attribute `to` doesn't exists.

I can't use a  `template match`   because i'm already in a `for-each`

Here is a snippet from my xsl :

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns3:jkm">
  <xsl:text>INSERT INTO JKM VALUES ('</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@code" />
  <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
  <!--<xsl:if test="not(ns3:Data[@to])">-->
    <xsl:value-of select="ns3:Data/@from and ns3:Data[not(@to)]" /> <!--doesn't work-->
  <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
  <!--</xsl:if>-->
  <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>-->
  <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select=".//ns2:Name" />
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>');</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing about your (american) date values is that they can be compared numerically without the `-` chars. So removing them enables a numeric comparison.
I also added some missing namespaces to your XML file and the XSLT to make the answer complete. Change the namespaces as you like - but equally in XML and XSLT.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:ExportMedicines xmlns:ns2="http://ns2.com" xmlns:ns3="http://ns3.com">
  <ns3:Jkm code="35897">
    <ns3:Data from="2016-10-01" to="2020-07-21">
      <ns2:Name>
        <Fr>estradiol 1 mg comp + estradiol 1 mg + dydrogestérone 10 mg comp</Fr> 
      </ns2:Name>
    </ns3:Data>
    <ns3:Data from="2020-07-22">
      <ns2:Name>
        <Fr>estradiol 2 mg comp+ estradiol 1 mg + dydrogestérone 10 mg comp</Fr>
      </ns2:Name>
  </ns3:Data>
  </ns3:Jkm>
</ns3:ExportMedicines>
```

**XSLT-1.0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  xmlns:ns2="http://ns2.com" xmlns:ns3="http://ns3.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  
    
    <xsl:template match="/ns3:ExportMedicines">
        <xsl:for-each select="ns3:Jkm">
            <xsl:text>INSERT INTO JKM VALUES ('</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@code" />
            <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns3:Data">
                <xsl:sort select="translate(@from,'-','')" order="descending" data-type="number" />
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:call-template name="escape-apos">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="ns2:Name" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>');</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is (the newest):**

```
INSERT INTO JKM VALUES ('35897','estradiol 2 mg comp+ estradiol 1 mg + dydrogestérone 10 mg comp','','','','');
```

This solution assumes that there is no overlapping between the `to` and the follwoing `from` value.

Comment: *"they can be compared numerically"* But you are sorting alphabetically. And for this, there is no need to remove the `-` characters.

Comment: Thank. I added the `data-type="number` attribute to explicitly indicate that it's a number though the result will be the same.

Comment: *"the result will be the same"* Right, so why bother. -- BTW: http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2014/10/americans-write-dates-differently-practically-everyone-else-relates-data-storage-holy-wars-soft-boiled-eggs/

Comment: I thought I wrote explicitly in my first sentence that _american_ dates (YYYY/MM/DD) can be compared this way. The TO used this format.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to do:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ns3:Jkm">
        <!-- omitted -->
        <xsl:value-of select="ns3:Data[not(@to)]/ns2:Name/Fr" /> 
        <!-- omitted -->
    </xsl:for-each>
```

This gets the value from the `Data` that does not have a `to` attribute - which I believe means it is current.

---

> I'm using xsl 1.0 so as i already read i can't test date attributes.

You are mistaken about that. Your dates are in the YYYY-MM-DD format - which means they can be used for sorting alphabetically as they are, with no modification necessary.